# How do I make this pointer work?

Tags: c, function, pointers, scanf

I have 2 functions. One called play_card and one called scan_card.

As you can see, in scan_card function, it scans in 3 numbers. However, I need to return those three numbers back to play_card. How can I do this with pointers?

```
void play_card(void) {

    int card_one;
    int card_two;
    int card_three;

    int card_array[] = {0};

    // Calls the scan_card function
    play_scanner(card_array);
    }

// Scans in the cards a user puts in
void scan_card(int card_array[]) {

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    *card_one = num1;
    *card_two = num2;
    *card_three = num3;
}
```

Comment: `card_one` and the other two are declared in the other function, meaning they won’t be accessible. You will also need to store the address of a variable in each pointer, not the value of it.

Comment: @Logan So I need to store the address here. Like this? `void scan_card(int *card_one, int *card_two, int *card_three, int card_array[])`

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.

Comment: @Logan What is the better way of doing it?

Comment: I would say that approach. You can also use global variables, but they shouldn’t be used often.

Comment: @Logan Oh no. That is frowned upon by my professor

Comment: Yes, haha. They can cause issues.

Comment: Create an array of 3 pointers in play_card and call scan_card by passing the array.Populate the array inside scan_card.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis What a clever way of doing it. Never thought about it like that. Only issue is, I actually need the values to be in words. So like, I want `card_one = 4;` So I can say if `card_one <= card_two` (because card_two actually means something). If I do `card[0] <= card[1]`, it will be confusing for the reader. Like `ice_cream_price <= apple_price`.

Comment: You could also have 3 pointers *card_one , *card_two,*card_three and pass those as a parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest implementation that comes to my mind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void play_card(void);
void scan_card(int* card_array[]);


int main()
{
    play_card();
    return 0;
}

void play_card(void)
{
    int* card_array[3];

    // Calls the scan_card function
    scan_card(card_array);
    int card_one = *card_array[0];
    int card_two = *card_array[1];
    int card_three = *card_array[2];
    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d\n" , card_one , card_two , card_three);
}

// Scans in the cards a user puts in
void scan_card(int* card_array[])
{

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    card_array[0] = &num1;
    card_array[1] = &num2;
    card_array[2] = &num3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the above answer,

This should work as you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void play_card(void);
void scan_card(int* card_array);


int main()
{
    play_card();
    return 0;
}

void play_card(void)
{
    int card_array[3];

    // Calls the scan_card function
    scan_card(card_array);
    int card_one   = card_array[0];
    int card_two   = card_array[1];
    int card_three = card_array[2];
    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d\n" , card_one , card_two , card_three);
}

// Scans in the cards a user puts in
void scan_card(int *card_array)
{

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

    card_array[0] = num1;
    card_array[1] = num2;
    card_array[2] = num3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
void play_card(void) {

int card_one;
int card_two;
int card_three;

int card_array[] = {0};

// Calls the scan_card function
play_scanner(card_array,&card_one,&card_two,&card_three);
}
void scan_card(int card_array[],int *card_one,int *card_two,int* card_three) 
{

int num1;
int num2;
int num3;

scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

*card_one = num1;
*card_two = num2;
*card_three = num3;
}
```